# Mini Test testing save on one and many trips

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails

I know there is a balance to be struck between writing dry code and damp code but I have the feeling that this is a bit too repeative. Is there a terse yet self explainatory way to rewrite these tests?

```
class TripTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @trip = trips(:one)
    @invoice = invoices(:one)
  end

  test 'trip can save' do
    trip = Trip.new
    trip.departure_date = "2040-03-24"
    trip.depart_airport = "DHW"
    trip.arrive_airport = "ABC"
    trip.invoice_id = 123534

    assert trip.save, "Error message: #{trip.errors.full_messages}"
  end

  test "one invoice can have multiple trips" do
    trip = Trip.new
    trip.departure_date = "2040-03-24"
    trip.depart_airport = "DHW"
    trip.arrive_airport = "ABC"
    trip.invoice_id = 123534
    @invoice.trips.push(trip)
    @invoice.save

    trip = Trip.new
    trip.departure_date = "2040-03-24"
    trip.depart_airport = "ICN"
    trip.arrive_airport = "XYZ"
    trip.invoice_id = 123534
    @invoice.trips.push(trip)
    @invoice.save

    assert @invoice.trips.size > 1
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing verbose tests, your test suite will skyrocket in length.

There are worse problems to have but your best asset to address this problem is a comprehensive `test_helper` class.

It doesn't matter what you call the file. Just load it up into your main test file with a `require_relative`.

In your example, it's fairly obvious which code is being repeated between methods. So you could refactor your code as follows:

```
# in test_helpers.rb
module TestHelpers
  def initialize_sample_trip(options={})
    Trip.new(
      departure_date: options[:departure_date]   || "2040-03-24"
      default_airport: options[:default_airport] || "DHW"
      arrive_airport: options[:arrive_airport]   || "ABC"
      invoice_id: options[:invoice_id]           || 123534
    )
  end
end
```

...

```
# in your main test file
require_relative './test_helpers.rb'
class TripTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include TestHelpers
  def setup
    @trip = trips(:one)
    @invoice = invoices(:one)
  end

  test 'trip can save' do
    trip = initialize_sample_trip
    assert trip.save, "Error message: #{trip.errors.full_messages}"
  end

  test "one invoice can have multiple trips" do
    trip1 = initialize_sample_trip
    @invoice.trips.push(trip1)
    @invoice.save
    trip2 = initialize_sample_trip(
      depart_airport: ICN, arrive_airport: "XYZ"
    )
    @invoice.trips.push(trip)
    @invoice.save
    assert @invoice.trips.size > 1
  end
```

This can be considered a "factory" design pattern. There are also various gems which can assist with this such as [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) or [faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker).